# @SuppressWarnings annotation on Application Level

Tags: java, annotations

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070260/combining-multiple-suppresswarnings-annotations-eclipse-indigo) question, where [`@SuppressWarnings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation is used on class level.

Suppose I have multiple classes in my application, so is there a way that I can use `@SuppressWarnings` on application level? As applying `@SuppressWarnings` on every class is redundant for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what javadoc says for `@SupressWarnings`

```
 @Target(value={TYPE,FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE})
 @Retention(value=SOURCE)
 public @interface SuppressWarnings
```

`@Target` clearly mentions places where @SupressWarnings can be applied. So you can not apply at  application level. Even doc go ahead and says

> As a matter of style, programmers should always use this annotation on the most deeply nested element where it is effective. If you want to suppress a warning in a particular method, you should annotate that method rather than its class.

So its discouraged to do at parent level where it is not applicable.